# How do i add new routes in the react-boilerplate?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-boilerplate

I have started to react code using https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate.
I just want to add login and registration from https://github.com/cornflourblue/react-redux-registration-login-example

But i met there is a store in two system, i have to merge them.

I just add some code in configureStore.js (boilerplate)

```
const store = createStore(
    createReducer({
      authentication, // from second project reducer
      registration,   // from second project reducer
      users,          // from second project reducer     
      alert           // from second project reducer
    }),
    fromJS(initialState),
    composeEnhancers(...enhancers)
  );
```

But the merged reducer doesn't work.

- Where do i have to add reducers in the react-boilerplate?

Comment: https://redux.js.org/api-reference/combinereducers

Comment: I did already, but i doesn't work.